# Why is there a bio-informatics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a lot of question tagged with "`bio-informatics`" and as far as I know there are **always** comments like:

> This is probably a better question for [biostars.org](https://www.biostars.org/)

Just like [this recent question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56500/is-there-a-good-database-with-info-about-gene-expression-and-hi-c-correlations). I'm wondering if these question are really off-topic and if this is the case why is there a `bio-informatics` tag? This may be quite misleading for new (or even experienced) people on this site, because this implicitly suggests that bio-informatics question are allowed.

Comment: Bioinformatics questions aren't off-topic here, and I haven't seen anyone say otherwise. I think people recommend biostars because they are more likely to get an answer there. For all we know, people who leave those comments are biostar employees!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it can be a bit confusing, but I think the problem is that many people come here with questions about *how to do* bioinformatics, rather than *how to relate bioinformatics results back to biology*. The former is off-topic, the latter is not. I'm not sure if the issue can be resolved, because the tag is still appropriate when the question is on-topic.